# is it necessary to create the init method and dealloc method explicit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

When I create a NSObject Class, is it necessary to create the init method and dealloc method explicit , is there a default method for them. I found that if I do not write the init method , a memory leak happend, why?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't write the `init` or `dealloc` method for your class then it has the inherited `init` and `dealloc` of the super class.
Unless you are not allocating any memory for you object members there will be no memory leakage.

Comment: Conversely, if you're doing manual reference counting (not using ARC or GC), your class owns resources, and you don't implement `-dealloc` to release them, then that is a leak.